# How to setup passport-identityserver3

Tags: node.js, identityserver3, node-red, passport.js

I am new with Node-red and passport-identityserver3.

I am having some difficulties how to setup the passport.

I installed the passport using the `C:\Users\xxx>npm install passport-identityserver3` command and try to set the `C:\Users\xxx\settings.js` file:

```
adminAuth: {
    type:"strategy",
    strategy: {
       name: "passport-identityserver3",
       label: 'Sign in with',
       icon:"an icon",
       strategy: require('passport-identityserver3').Strategy,
       options: {
           configuration_endpoint: 'http://localhost:xxxx/.well-known/openid-configuration',
           client_id: 'my_client_id',
           client_secret: 'my_client_secret',
           callback_url: 'http://localhost:1880/auth/strategy/callback',
           scopes: ['profile', 'offline_access'],
           },
           verify: function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
               done(null, profile);
        }
    },
    users: [
       { username: "admin",permissions: ["*"]}
    ]
},
```

I am getting the following error:

```
http://127.0.0.1:1880/auth/strategy

Error: Unknown authentication strategy "passport-identityserver3"
    at attempt (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-
    red\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:173:37)
    at authenticate (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-
    red\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:349:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 
    (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-
    red\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-
    red\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-
    red\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 
    (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-
    red\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-
    red\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params 
    (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-
    red\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-
    red\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at SessionStrategy.strategy.pass 
    (C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-
    red\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:325:9)
```

Thanks you.

Comment: Edit the question to show EXACTLY what you installed and what directory you were in at the time you ran the npm commands.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the `npm i passport-identityserver3` in the Node-RED User Directory. By default this should be:

```
C:\Users\xxx\.node-red
```

not

```
C:\Users\xxx\
```

The `settings.js` file should also be in this directory. When you start Node-RED it will list which User Directory and `settings.js` it is using

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am still get the same error :-(